# Django rest framework - Serializer always returns empty object ({})

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am creating first rest api in django using django rest framework

I am unable to get object in json format. Serializer always returns empty object {}

models.py

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
```

serializers.py

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def auth(request):
    username = request.data['username']
    password = request.data['password']
    statusCode = status.HTTP_200_OK
    try:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                
                context_data = request.data
                
                shop = model_to_dict(Shop.objects.get(retailer_id = username))
                shop_serializer = ShopSerializer(data=shop)
                if shop:
                    try:
                        
                        if shop_serializer.is_valid():
                            print('is valid')
                            print(shop_serializer.data)
                            context_data = shop_serializer.data
                        else:
                            print('is invalid')
                            print(shop_serializer.errors)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

                else:
                    print('false')
            else:
                pass
        else:
            context_data = {
                    "Error": {
                        "status": 401,
                        "message": "Invalid credentials",
                        }
                    }
            statusCode = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    return Response(context_data, status=statusCode)
```

When i try to print **print(shop_data)** it always returns empty object

Any help, why object is empty rather than returning Shop object in json format?

Edited:

I have updated the code with below suggestions mentioned. But now, when shop_serializer.is_valid() is executed i get below error

{'shop_id': [ErrorDetail(string='shop with this shop shop_id already exists.', code='unique')]}

With the error it seems it is trying to update the record but it should only get the record and serialize it into json.

Answer (score 5):

You're using a standard `Serializer` class in this code fragment:

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = '__all__'
```

This class won't read the contend of the `Meta` subclass and won't populate itself with fields matching the model class. You probably meant to use `ModelSerializer` instead.

If you really want to use the `Serializer` class here, you need to populate it with correct fields on your own.

Comment: Updated the code with ModelSerializer. See the edited code plz. It gives me error like if it is trying to update the record

Answer (score 0):

.data - Only available after calling `is_valid()`, Try to check if serializer is valid than take it's data

Comment: Added is_valid() and now it is trying to update the record rather it should only get the record. Please see the updated code

Comment: Then on get request don't use serializer, just pass that line shop = model_to_dict(Shop.objects.get(retailer_id = username)), into your Response(context_data), actually i think you can get rid of serializer on get request